# Font File Errors | Open Graph Images Next Js 13 App Directory

Tags: next.js, facebook-opengraph, next.js13

I tried the [Generate images using code (.js, .ts, .tsx)](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/opengraph-image#generate-images-using-code-js-ts-tsx).

But I got an error from my font files.

[image]

Here's my code, mostly copy paste from the next js app directory documentation

```
import { ImageResponse } from 'next/server'

// Route segment config
export const runtime = 'edge'

// Image metadata
export const alt = "Online Personal Portfolio"
export const size = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 630,
}

export const contentType = 'image/png'

// Font
const interSemiBold = fetch(
    new URL("../../public/Inter-SemiBold.ttf", import.meta.url)
).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())

// Image generation
export default async function Image() {
    return new ImageResponse(
        (
            // ImageResponse JSX element
            <div
                tw='flex flex-col bg-neutral-900 w-full h-full justify-center items-center'
            >
                <p tw='text-4xl text-neutral-100'>
                    Online Personal Portfolio
                </p>
            </div>
        ),
        // ImageResponse options
        {
            // For convenience, we can re-use the exported opengraph-image
            // size config to also set the ImageResponse's width and height.
            ...size,
            fonts: [
                {
                    name: 'Inter',
                    data: await interSemiBold,
                    style: 'normal',
                    weight: 400,
                },
            ],
        }
    )
}
```

and here's my file directory

```
|--- public
| |---Inter-SemiBold.ttf
|--- src
| |--- app
| | |--- opengraph-image.tsx
```

Can anyone show what's the problem and how to solve it?